# Python app not working after using pyinstaller but doesn't give any errors

Tags: python, pyinstaller, kivy-language

So I made an app using python and kvlang, and I was trying to get all the files into a one standalone "exe" file. I needed to include the ".kv" file and my main script. I was using pyinstaller and wrote this command:

`pyinstaller --onefile -w --icon=download.ico --add-data filefinder.kv;. filefinder.py`

And it all went well - no errors or anything but when I launch the app I just get a quick flash of a white window and then it closes. I have determined that the error must be because of some issue with the ".kv" file but I am not able to fix it cause there's no errors, Nothing! I checked and the app works with the "onedir" option but I need to make it smaller in size. I also tried the "auto-py-to-exe" but it gives the same result. I am happy to provide any more info should you need it to help me resolve this issue. Cheers!

Additional info:

System: Windows 10 pro

Python: 3.9.1

kivy: 2.0.0

Pyinstaller: 4.2

Comment: What happens if you run your main python script in command prompt ?

Comment: The app starts up normally.

Comment: Follow the advice in the `pyinstaller` docs about *When things go wrong*. Wrapping the Python interpreter, your program and all its dependencies into an `.exe` is quite complex, and there may be more things that need to be set up by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't work, but run the exe in command prompt and then when it fails the error message will not disappear.

Add lots of logs to your application, these can be print statements, as those will always end up on stdout.

i.e. on the first entrypoint, `print("Running main")`
When you call your first function:
`print('calling function_name()')`

Once that has finished

`print('function_name() complete')`

And so on and so forth until you find where exactly the program stops functioning.

Start -> cmd -> navigate to your file using cd -> type in the name of the exe to run it.

Comment: I ran it from command prompt but it doesn't give me anything, just a white flash and the command prompt just moves onto another command line.

Comment: I found the error I think, I get [INFO] Tags and the information in them that some libs were not found BUT then I get [CRITICAL] [APP              ] Unable to get a Window, Abort" and then it starts doing a clean-up job.