# How to create kivy applications for desktop in Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, kivy, pyinstaller, kivymd

Good afternoon people.

Once again trying to package kivy for DESKTOP on WINDOWS 10 and to no avail!

I had a lot of errors that I managed to solve without disturbing the order in the groups but this one is phoda with ph.

1 - I create the exe using Auto_py_to_exe and before there is any comment that I should use pyinstaller, I tell you, the same thing happens!

2 - My pyinstaller script is as follows:

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --name "TeuCu" --add-data "C: /Users/Elias/Desktop/kv_inventario/inventario/main.kv ;." --add-data "C: / Users / Elias / Desktop / kv_inventario / inventario / images; images /" "C: /Users/Elias/Desktop/kv_inventario/inventario/main.py"

3 - The error is exactly like this, when running the application after it is created it returns this error:

```
[CRITICAL] [Window] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image 
File "kivy\core\__init__.py", line 70, in core_select_lib
   File "kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
   File "kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 982, in __init__
   File "kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 311, in create_window
   File "kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1268, in create_window
   File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 783, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__
   File "kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 561, in __init__
   File "kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 754, in _set_filename
   File "kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 460, in load
   File "kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 223, in __init__
   File "kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 47, in load

[CRITICAL] [App] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

My solution that could possibly work would be this tip that I found in kivy issues:
[Kivy issues](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4115)

This took me to the post below and translating it asks to uninstall the pillow and reinstall with the wheel

```
python3 -m pip3 uninstall pillow
python3 -m pip3 install --use-wheel pillow
```

But it didn't.

I would like your help. Who managed to generate an application for Windows with kivy

I'm using Windows 10 to package.

Comment: I have succeeded in creating a kivy executable on Windows 10 that works, however the best way I could help you is to, give you a link to my video on youtube I made right after trying to package it into a single exe for weeks. Do you want to see this video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is common - Here are some helpful links:

[Kivy not working (Error: Unable to find any valuable Window provider.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219563/kivy-not-working-error-unable-to-find-any-valuable-window-provider)

[Python app not working after using pyinstaller but doesn't give any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874054/python-app-not-working-after-using-pyinstaller-but-doesnt-give-any-errors)

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6342

https://github.com/pal1000/save-legacy-intel-graphics

[Kivy does not detect OpenGL 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969990/kivy-does-not-detect-opengl-2-0)
[Windows- Pyinstaller Error "failed to execute script " When App Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716346/windows-pyinstaller-error-failed-to-execute-script-when-app-clicked)

[Unable to get a window, abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697876/unable-to-get-a-window-abort)

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6276

If none of these work, I also made a video on packaging a kivy app to a single exe for Windows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9Hx0q5Sopg

Please let me know if you succeed. Cheers!